# String pattern matching in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pattern-matching, string-matching

I am trying to create a View on a Log table.  A lot of the logs are from "potentially dangerous form requests", and while I'm interested in capturing these, they also create a lot of noise, so I'd like to have a view that filters them out.  The logging is coming from a CMS, so I cannot modify the logic for that.

The log entries I'd like to filter out are *always* in the format of

```
At /contact-us.aspx (Referred by: http://www.mydomain.com/contact-us.aspx): 
At /login.aspx (Referred by: http://www.mydomain.com/login.aspx):
```

So basically I want a `where` clause where I can say something to the effect of

```
where logComment <> 'At [url] (Referred by: http://www.mydomain.com[url]);'
```

How can I accomplish this in the form of a query that can be used for a View?  I have tried toying around with `PatIndex` and read a bit about Regex in SQL, but I'm running into dead ends with both.

Comment: But `[url]` can be arbitrary. Not just the two examples there presumably? Are all the log entries in the form `At ???? (Referred`?

Comment: @Martin Smith - yes, [url] is arbitrary.  Can be anything, but will be the same in both places in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should return anything not matching the pattern `'At % (Referred%'` at all or not matching the pattern specified in the question.

```
WITH Log(logComment)
     AS (SELECT 'At /contact-us.aspx (Referred by: http://www.mydomain.com/contact-us.aspx)'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'At /login.aspx (Referred by: http://www.mydomain.com/login.aspx)'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'FOOBAR')
SELECT logComment
FROM   Log
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT 
                    CASE
                    WHEN logComment LIKE 'At % (Referred%' 
                    THEN SUBSTRING(logComment, 4, CHARINDEX('(Referred', logComment) - 5)
                    END) C(url)
WHERE  url IS NULL
        OR logComment <> 'At ' + url + ' (Referred by: http://www.mydomain.com' + url + ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard character for TSQL is the % sign.  Try this:

```
WHERE logComment NOT LIKE 'At % (Referred by: http://www.mydomain.com%);'
```

Comment: That doesn't ensure the `%` matched at the start is the same string as that matched at the end.

Comment: @Martin Smith hit the nail on the head.  I started with that, but ran into errors where it might be `At [media file] Referred by [url]`.  Don't want to lose those.

Comment: Good point.  I missed that subtlety in the original question.  You could use a scalar UDF, but the cross-apply example by @Martin Smith is more elloquent/compact.